# Relationship between Skeleton and Tempo

Tags: skeleton

Emacs ships with two packages for creating and inserting templates: Tempo and Skeleton. As far as I can tell, they fulfill the same purpose. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is pretty accurate. In some cases, Emacs provides a package which does something, then a better package comes along which also is included. For example, Emacs comes with two perl major modes (`perl-mode` and `cperl-mode`).

Comment: But in this case, I don't think either package actually supersedes the other. If so, it isn't clear which one is the better one.